# https calls to local server with a self signed certificate are blocked on chrome (works on FF)

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I've created a certificate and a key using openssl, and using node.js to server a simple (hello world) file.

Chrome acts like the request never gets to the server (server logs too confirms).
Firefox warns about the certificate, but lets you access the file.
See attached image.

Any ideas?

OS: mac 10.9.5
Chrome: Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of certificates is to be *signed* by a third entity, called a Certificate Authority (CA). A client will generally not accept a certificate given by a server unless the server produces a certificate signed by a CA specifically known to the client.

The 'identity' of a CA and the process of 'signature' are cryptographic concepts that are very precise and strict in order to avoid bad guys impersonating other people (your bank, Google, etc.).

Browsers usually allow you to accept untrusted certificates on a per-session basis, because bad certificates are everywhere and are not necessarily always a sign of malicious activity going on. However automatic code (Node.js included) will almost universally reject bad cetrtificates, because there's no way to ask a user for an override.

What you need to do is to generate a CA certificate and instruct you node.js client to trust it. I think the following links to a valid sample:
https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-ssl-trusted-peer-example. Look specifically at request.js - the relevant line is

`fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'client', 'my-root-ca.crt.pem'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot this further. Try other clients or an http(s) proxy.
Specifically I would try other browsers, https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze, Fiddler, curl, and other similar tools.